# How i can find my Drupal version in DB?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am having only the sites folder(except Default Directory) and DB of a website with that how can i find my version.

ACtually in my DB they had fixed the prefix 'd6_' with that i can find it as Drupal6. But i can't find the correct Version of Drupal6.

Answer (score 3):

In the info column of your system table in drupal database you can find the serialize text something like ""package";s:4:"Core";s:7:"version";s:4:"7.43";s:4:"core";s:3:"7.x";" of any core modules like aggrigator or block.

when you un-serialize the string you can find the version of drupal 
e.g

```
[version] => 7.43
[core] => 7.x
```

This is the drupal version 7.43

Thanks